# "HTTP_USER_AGENT" not working. nothing is displayed in my browser i.e. firefox

Tags: php, environment-variables

```
<?php
$agent=getenv("HTTP_USER_AGENT");
if(preg_match("/MSIE/i", "$agent")){
    $result="You are using Microsoft Internet Explorer.";}
    else if (preg_match("/Mozilla/i", "$agent")){
    $result= "You are using Firefox.";}
    else {$result = " you are using $agent.";}

?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Browse Match Results</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php "<p>$result</p>";?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: um... what's your PHP look like? That's not going to work in anything.

Comment: try $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] and is your browser sending a user agent string?

Comment: i am using Dreamweaver and learning from the Book PHP6 fast and easy web development. i typed the code given in it and it doesnt seem to be working.

Comment: browser just refreshes and displays nothing

Comment: FYI, [that book is generally looked down upon as teaching bad practices](http://www.amazon.com/PHP-Fast-Easy-Web-Development/dp/1598634712#customerReviews).  Given the code sample you've provided here, it's pretty clear why...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might I venture a guess, and suggest that:

```
<?php "<p>$result</p>";?>
```

Should be:

```
<?php echo "<p>$result</p>";?>
```

Comment: hey Wrikken u r freaking awesome...i wonder for how much time have u been into PHP.
i misread from the book :P

Answer (score 0):

`<?php` **echo** `"<p>$result</p>";?>`